# Mixed distribution

Tags: distributions

Bob is a carnival operator of a game in which a player receives a prize worth $W=2^N$ if the player has $N$ successes, $N=0,1,2,3,...$ Bob models the probability of success for a player as follows:
i)$N$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$

ii)$\lambda$ has a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,4)$.

Calculate $E(W)$

My attempt,

$$E(W)=E(2^N)$$

$$=P_N(2)$$

$$P_N(z)=E(z^N)$$

$$=E(E(Z^N|\lambda))$$

I'm stuck at here. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're in correct path:

$$E[2^N|\lambda]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^ne^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\lambda)^n}{n!}=e^{2\lambda}e^{-\lambda}=e^\lambda$$

Then, we calculate $E[e^\lambda]$, which is trivial.